# Angular route - combine data from multiple resolvers

Tags: angular-router, angular-resolver

I have this route:

```
path: 'route-to',
component: component,
resolve: { model: resolver },
data: { resolvedata: 'module_name'}
```

In resolver's resolve method I have an http call:

```
const moduleName = route.data.resolvedata;
const translationUrl = moduleName + '/' + 'en_us';
return this.translateService.use(translationUrl).pipe(
        catchError((error) => {
            return [];
        })
    );
```

I need to get another translation module into the same route.
So, is it possible to combine two http calls in such fashion that the resolver will return data from both calls?

Thanks